# Casperjs how to pass agruments containing parenthesis

Tags: casperjs

I just came accross a curious behaviour with casperjs. 
When passing arguments to my script using the console or a curl, if there is a right parenthesis ')' on my string, it makes casperjs crash and it throws an error indicating that everything after the parenthesis is unexpected.

I tried backslashing the parenthesis but without success.

Here is an example I type in command line :

```
casperjs C:/wamp64/www/casperscripts/my-casper.js plop)dddd
```

It gives me the error "dddd is unexpected"

Do you have something to help me ? 
(before you ask, the content of my-casper.js is not a problem, I totaly emptied it to try and it's the same)
Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your argument within quotation marks:

```
casperjs C:/wamp64/www/casperscripts/my-casper.js "plop)dddd"
```

Then, you can access the result with:

```
casper.cli.get(0)
```